# Creating a entire folder structure in one call using MS Graph-Api

Tags: java, spring, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, directory-structure

I have a situation where i need to programmatically create a folder and all its subfolders including their subfolders into a sharepoint documment library.
Is it possibible to do that in 1 call?

Right now i do it folder by folder which does take a noticeable amount of time since there are many subfolders. Here is how i do it:

```
//newFolder - The folder that i want to create, contains subfolders
//destinationFolder - The destination folder where i want to create newFolder
public void createFolder(ExternalDocumentFolder newFolder, ExternalDocumentFolder destinationFolder) {
    GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = graphServiceClientBuilder.buildForNoUser();
    String driveID = getDriveID(graphClient);

    //All subfolders are flattened into a single list for easy of saving
    List<ExternalDocumentFolder> externalDocumentFolders = flattenFolder(newFolder);
    for (ExternalDocumentFolder folder : externalDocumentFolders) {
        DriveItem newDriveItem = mapToDriveItem(folder);
        String destinationPath = destinationFolder.getPath();
        if(folder.getParent() != null){
            destinationPath = destinationPath + "/" + folder.getParent().getPath();
        }
        DriveItem returnedDriveItem = graphClient.drives(driveID).items("root:/" + destinationPath + ":").children().buildRequest().post(newDriveItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a batch request to combine all the requests into a single call. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp).

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma It worked. If you want, make an answer so i can accept it

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a batch request to combine all the requests into a single call. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=csharp).

Comment: Well, actually, while it did work, and cut the required time in half, it still is not good enough. Does Microsoft really do not provide the option to create a entire folder structure?

Comment: AFAIK, They didn't have that option but you can request for this kind of feature at [Ideas site](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5001530) so that it can be available in future

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to create a folder structure from one batch call. I'm not sure if this has been added recently, but it can be done like this:

Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4

```
$folders = [
  "id" => 1,
  "method" => "POST",
  "url" => "/drives/DRIVE_ID/root:/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3:/children",
  "body" => [
   "name" => 'Folder4',
   "folder" => new stdClass(),
   "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" => "fail"
  ],
  "headers" => [
   "Content-Type" => "application/json"
  ]
];
```

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$create = $guzzle->request("POST", "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch", [
  "headers" => [
    "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    "Accept" => "application/json",
    "Authorization" => "Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
  ],
  "json" => [
    "requests" => [$folders]
  ]
]);
$response = $create->getStatusCode();
```

Hope that helps someone. Make sure the "name" param contains the last folder. Seems to work pretty well.

Comment: That works for me too! That functionality is not really documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http